# If $A A^{-1} = I$, does that automatically imply $A^{-1} A = I$?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Or, in other words, if $A A^{-1} = I$ is satisfied, is there a possibility that $A^{-1} A \neq I$?

My suspicion is the answer is no.

Comment: If $A^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $A$, then by definition of inverse $A^{-1}A = AA^{-1} = I$.

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is by definition an inverse on both sides.  There are left inverses and right inverses, but they are not written as $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Something to think about: $$\begin{align*}\mathbf A\mathbf A^{-1}&=\mathbf I\\\mathbf A\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf A&=\mathbf I\mathbf A=\mathbf A\\\mathbf A(\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf A)&=\mathbf A\mathbf I\end{align*}$$ recalling associativity. Is the identity element unique? ;)

Comment: That depends on what $A^{-1}$ means. See [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852).

Comment: @j.m. is a poor mathematician. In the last argument you used that A*A(inverse)=I , which has not been shown yet

Comment: "which has not been shown yet" - isn't that what you were assuming in the first place?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are finite matrices with $AB = I$, then we must have $B A = I$ also. This is because the finite-dimensionality together with $AB = I$ forces $A$ and $B$ to be bijections, and hence each is invertible as a linear map between vector spaces. This fails in the infinite-dimensional setting: we might have $AB = I$, but neither $A$ nor $B$ is invertible.

Comment: @Joppy you need that $A$ and $B$ are square as well.  As alluded to earlier, you can have non-square matrices $A$ and $B$ of sizes $m\times n$ and $n\times m$ such that $AB=I_m$.  Take $(1~0)$ and $\binom{1}{0}$ for instance which multiply to give $(1)$, the $1\times 1$ identity matrix, but multiplying in the other order doesn't.  $f\circ g$ a bijection doesn't directly imply $f$ and $g$ are both bijections.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes that’s true, I forgot to mention that since when talking about invertible matrices I only ever have square matrices in mind! But it’s a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes AA<sup>-1</sup> = A<sup>-1</sup>A = I when the Det(A)$\neq$0 and A is a square matrix.

### Long Answer

A matrix is basically a linear transformation applied to some space. For the sake of simplicity I will assume that we are in a 2D plane having 2 basis vectors i<sup>^</sup> and j<sup>^</sup> each having the magnitude of 1 with coordinates (1,0) and (0,1) respectively. The columns of the matrix tells where the corresponding basis vectors lands after the transformation.

A<sup>-1</sup>A means that first we apply A transformation then we apply A<sup>-1</sup> transformation. When we apply A transformation we reach some plane having some different basis vectors but after apply A<sup>-1</sup> we again reach to the plane have basis i<sup>^</sup> (0,1) and j<sup>^</sup> (1,0). It means that after applying A<sup>-1</sup> we reach to the transformation which does nothing. **The identity transformation** $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$.
It is basically the plane we started before applying A transformation. 

That's why A<sup>-1</sup>A = I.

This is same as AA<sup>-1</sup>. It means that we first apply the A<sup>-1</sup> transformation which will take as to some plane having different basis vectors. If we think what is the inverse of A<sup>-1</sup> ? We are basically asking that what transformation is required to get back to the Identity transformation whose basis vectors are i<sup>^</sup>(1,0) and j<sup>^</sup>(0,1). Transformation A will do the job, since in this case after applying the A transformation we will reach to the identity transformation.

**That's why 
AA<sup>-1</sup> = I**

Comment: thank you sir, i forgot to think about matrices as linear transformations but that makes sense indeed

Comment: @SteezO- I am glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The result is not true for non-square matrices, since their left and right inverses are not equal.

Comment: How would you even define an identity matrix for non-square matrices?